# How to format dplyr output in R into doubles (or other workable format)?

Tags: r, vector, dplyr, tibble

How do I get the outcome of this to be numerical values versus tibbles.

```
prop_smoking <- df %>% 
    group_by(Age) %>%
    summarise(ratio = sum(Smoking == 'yes')/n())
```

This gives me output like this:

```
Age     Ratio
18-24  .134
25-35  .144
36-50  .189
```

I want to add each value to its corresponding vector because I am using a resampling approach. However, if I index in the following way: `prop_smoking[1,2]` it gives me a tibble type. Therefore, when I add it to its corresponding vector and want to do things like loop through and subtract the mean as I would with a vector, I get a "non-numeric argument to binary operator". How can I index or convert the values so they are easy to work with (i.e. `doubles`)

Comment: Including a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) in your question will increase your chances of getting an answer.

Comment: `as.numeric(prop_smoking[1,2])` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

coerce it to a dataframe.

```
prop_smoking <- as.data.frame(prop_smoking)
```